# Hive return no values if used with function

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, apache-tez

I have a strange problem with hive shell. I created a Hadoop system using Apache original packages. I use tez.

To test the system I loaded the NY taxi data into hive without any problem. The data set has about 11 Million lines. If I do select staments in hive shell it is working. If I use functions like this

```
select count(*) from yellow;
```

or

```
select sum(trip_distance) from yellow where trip_distance is not null;
```

that the process runs through without any problem but return only OK. If I do the same in spark-sql I get the answer. Also If I do group by statements the result is the same.

The table definition is

```
CREATE TABLE `default.yellow` ( `VendorID` int , `tpep_pickup_datetime` timestamp , `tpep_dropoff_datetime` timestamp , `passenger_count` bigint , `trip_distance` float , `pickup_longitude` float , `pickup_latitude` float , `RatecodeID` bigint , `store_and_fwd_flag` string , `dropoff_longitude` float , `dropoff_latitude` float , `payment_type` bigint , `fare_amount` int , `extra` float , `mta_tax` float , `tip_amount` int , `tolls_amount` bigint , `improvement_surcharge` float , `total_amount` float ) COMMENT "yellow" stored as ORC
```

This is in ORC format. I used also Parquet but no difference in the result.

And also other tables showed only the OK result if I count the lines.

Here are some sample lines, as mentioned this are free available NY taxi data which I used for testing.

```
2,2016-06-09 21:06:36.0,2016-06-09 21:13:08.0,2,0.79,-73.98336,40.760937,1,N,-73.97746,40.75398,2,6,0.5,0.5,0,0,0.3,7.3
2,2016-06-09 21:06:36.0,2016-06-09 21:35:11.0,1,5.22,-73.98172,40.736668,1,N,-73.981636,40.670242,1,22,0.5,0.5,4,0,0.3,27.3
2,2016-06-09 21:06:36.0,2016-06-09 21:13:10.0,1,1.26,-73.994316,40.751072,1,N,-74.004234,40.74217,1,6,0.5,0.5,1,0,0.3,9.36
2,2016-06-09 21:06:36.0,2016-06-09 21:36:10.0,1,7.39,-73.98236,40.77389,1,N,-73.92947,40.85154,1,26,0.5,0.5,1,0,0.3,28.3
```

Comment: Please supply the table definition and some sample rows

Comment: Check mapreduce stack traces to get more insights.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the issue. I  I have you loaded the NY taxi data into hive? What do you get for `select * from yellow limit 10`?

Comment: I get the 10 lines as output. No problem with this. I tested also max, min, and other functions all have the same result. No output 0 lines. I have the feeling tez is doing something wrong. But I'm not sure until now.

Comment: If I switch hive to from tez back to map reduce I get the correct output. I have to redeploy tez. Something terrible wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is the solution. Hive and tez log showed also no problem at all. Also the number of lines given by tez was correct.

So the only possible problem could be in the communication between hive and tez. And due to some unknown reasons the mapred-site.xml had no value, because at start it was set. After I set it back to the correct value yarn-tez it worked.